# Django Template - Cannot iterate throught this list

Tags: python, django

I am passing this object to my template from my view with the name `student_collection`

```
<class 'list'>: [[31, 'John', ‘Jacob', '1'], [31, 'Jeffrey', ‘Mark', '2'], [39, ‘Borris', ‘Hammer', '1']]
```

And accessing it as such in my template:

```
{% for rows in student_collection %}
<tr>
    {% for items in rows %}

        {% for entry in items %}
        <td>{{ entry }}</td>
        {% endfor %}

    {% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I am getting an error at the point  `{% for entry in items %}` django says 'int' `object is not iterable` why is that I was expecting to iterate through `31,John,Jacob,1` . Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was expecting to iterate through `31,John,Jacob,1`

Then you wouldn't need that second inner loop. The first loop gives you each sublist/row in the list of rows, while the inner loop iterates through each row, producing each of the items/entries:

```
{% for rows in student_collection %}
    <tr>
          {% for item in row %}
              <td>{{ item }}</td>
          {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```